# Where to find the SendGrid settings fields in MySql

Tags: sendgrid

I have WordPress multisite network. I need to query my database to find which sites have the SendGrid settings as blank?

Which field can query or where I can find the SendGrid field in MySql?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [SendGrid for WordPress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sendgrid-email-delivery-simplified/) that stores credentials in the `wp_options` table with the `option_name`s of: `sendgrid_username` and `sendgrid_pwd`.

As you're using WordPress multisite, these options tables will be named `wp_1_options`, `wp_2_options`, and so forth.

You may query these tables to see which sites do not have the rows with `option_name`s of `sendgrid_username` and `sendgrid_pwd` (or which do, but have the corresponding `option_value` defined).